# rotating a physics object in lua

Tags: android, ios, lua, rotation, coronasdk

The problem I am having is rotating an object and moving on to the next scene in lua. 
I have a function that returns delta time as following:

```
local runtime = 0
local function getDeltaTime()
   local temp = system.getTimer()  
   local dt = (temp-runtime) / (1000/200)
   runtime = temp
   return dt
end
```

Then inside my `createScene`, I have `frameUpdate()` function as following:

```
local function frameUpdate()


     local dt = getDeltaTime()

    wood5.rotation = wood5.rotation -(1*dt)
    wood6.rotation = wood6.rotation -(1*dt)

end
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", frameUpdate )
```

wood5 and wood6 are initialized above with rotation values `90` and `0` respectively.

The issue here is when I am switching scenes using my "next scene" button. The two woods would rotate fine, but as soon as I hit the "next", "back", or "reset" button, it shows me an error and says "`attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'rotation' (a nil value)`" I tried printing the values of `wood5.rotation` and `wood5.rotation`, they were `90` and `0` the first time, but they became huge negative numbers later on. Something like :

```
-3430.9887695313
-3520.9877929688
```

.
.etc

Comment: Show the code where you initialize your wood rotation fields; this code is not being executed. alternately, you have a `wood5.rotation = something` (where `something` doesnt' refer to `wood5.rotation`) somewhere in your code, and the something is nil. I'm not familiar with Corona, is "next" the same as "next scene", and "back" is previous scene, and "reset" goes to first scene? Does some code get executed every time you switch scenes? If so, show that code too, it is key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before scene change, call:

```
Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", frameUpdate )
```

and inside your function, check for the existance of the object as:

```
if(wood5~=nil)then
wood5.rotation = wood5.rotation -(1*dt)
end
```

Keep Coding.................... :)